# XSLT - Remove spaces and hyphens from element that shows up more than once

Tags: xml, xslt, element, repeat, iban

I am working through a payment integration transformation. One xml payment fie can contain more than one payment. because of this there will be more than one instances of IBAN (). I need my XSLT to remove all spaces and hyphens from the one or many instances of . XML below. I have exhausted all options. as for this project this is the only art I need answers on. In the XML sample below there are two instances of IBAN. I have tried for-each, storing and removing characters in variable (ends up concat values in both elements)...  any help would be great. This is sample data and not actual payment data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <GrpHdr>
         <MsgId>FILEREFT2</MsgId>
         <CreDtTm>2016-07-05T14:20:07</CreDtTm>
         <NbOfTxs>2</NbOfTxs>
         <CtrlSum>251000.50</CtrlSum>
         <InitgPty>
            <Nm>Test Client</Nm>
            <Id>
               <OrgId>
                  <Othr>
                     <Id>CLIENT ID</Id>
                  </Othr>
               </OrgId>
            </Id>
         </InitgPty>
      </GrpHdr>
      <PmtInf>
         <PmtInfId>BATCHREF</PmtInfId>
         <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
         <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
         <CtrlSum>251000.50</CtrlSum>
         <PmtTpInf>
            <SvcLvl>
               <Cd>URGP</Cd>
            </SvcLvl>
         </PmtTpInf>
         <ReqdExctnDt>2016-07-05</ReqdExctnDt>
         <Dbtr>
            <Nm>This Is My Debtor</Nm>
            <PstlAdr>
               <PstCd>ABCD1XXX</PstCd>
               <TwnNm>London</TwnNm>
               <CtrySubDvsn>Regent's Place</CtrySubDvsn>
               <Ctry>GB</Ctry>
               <AdrLine>10 A Street</AdrLine>
            </PstlAdr>
         </Dbtr>
         <DbtrAcct>
            <Id>
               <IBAN>GB-29NWBK 601613319268 19</IBAN>
            </Id>
            <Ccy>GBP</Ccy>
         </DbtrAcct>
         <DbtrAgt>
            <FinInstnId>
               <BIC>NWBKGB2L</BIC>
               <ClrSysMmbId>
                  <MmbId>601613</MmbId>
               </ClrSysMmbId>
               <PstlAdr>
                  <TwnNm>London</TwnNm>
                  <Ctry>GB</Ctry>
                  <AdrLine>London</AdrLine>
               </PstlAdr>
            </FinInstnId>
         </DbtrAgt>
         <CdtTrfTxInf>
            <PmtId>
               <InstrId>TRXREFT2</InstrId>
               <EndToEndId>TRXREFT2</EndToEndId>
            </PmtId>
            <Amt>
               <InstdAmt Ccy="GBP">251000.50</InstdAmt>
            </Amt>
            <ChrgBr>SHAR</ChrgBr>
            <CdtrAgt>
               <FinInstnId>
                  <BIC>MIDLGB22XXX</BIC>
                  <ClrSysMmbId>
                     <MmbId>404865</MmbId>
                  </ClrSysMmbId>
                  <PstlAdr>
                     <Ctry>GB</Ctry>
                  </PstlAdr>
               </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Cdtr>
               <Nm>My Creditor</Nm>
               <PstlAdr>
                  <TwnNm>Leeds</TwnNm>
                  <Ctry>GB</Ctry>
                  <AdrLine>Palace Square</AdrLine>
               </PstlAdr>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
               <Id>
                  <IBAN>GB-32ESSE40486562136016</IBAN>
               </Id>
            </CdtrAcct>
            <RmtInf>
               <Ustrd>Free Text- This is a CHAPS payment 12345.</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
         </CdtTrfTxInf>          <CdtTrfTxInf>
            <PmtId>
               <InstrId>TRXREFT3</InstrId>
               <EndToEndId>TRXREFT3</EndToEndId>
            </PmtId>
            <Amt>
               <InstdAmt Ccy="GBP">1000.3</InstdAmt>
            </Amt>
            <ChrgBr>SHAR</ChrgBr>
            <CdtrAgt>
               <FinInstnId>
                  <BIC>MIDLGB22XXX</BIC>
                  <ClrSysMmbId>
                     <MmbId>404865</MmbId>
                  </ClrSysMmbId>
                  <PstlAdr>
                     <Ctry>GB</Ctry>
                  </PstlAdr>
               </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Cdtr>
               <Nm>My Creditor</Nm>
               <PstlAdr>
                  <TwnNm>Leeds</TwnNm>
                  <Ctry>GB</Ctry>
                  <AdrLine>Spire Apparel</AdrLine>
               </PstlAdr>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
               <Id>
                  <IBAN>GB32ESSE404865621360 16</IBAN>
               </Id>
            </CdtrAcct>
            <RmtInf>
               <Ustrd>Free Text- This is a FASTER payment 12345.</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
         </CdtTrfTxInf>
      </PmtInf>     </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>  </Document>
```

Comment: Don't tell us you've exhausted all options, choose one of the options that you tried which didn't work, tell us what you did, and tell us how it failed. That way we get an idea what part of the spec you don't understand, and we can help you over that particular obstacle,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what version of XSLT you're using, but this should cover all of them...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:idk="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="idk:IBAN/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'- ','')"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It uses the [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying) and [`translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-translate).

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxNakAf

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN!!!!!!! something so simple yet so elegant!!  This worked perfectly. This was a great lesson.